# jQuery JSONP sending the autogenerated callback name in data parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, jsonp

I'm getting data from a remote server, that can produce JSONP but needs the callback-function name in a non-standard way.

For code structure & simpler error-handling, I'd prefer to use the default function. Is there a way for me to get the autogenerated function name, and give that as a data-parameter?

What I'd like to be able to do is something in the lines of:

```
    $.ajax("http://mydomain.com/xxx",
        {
            dataType: "jsonp",
            type : 'GET',
            success : function(response) {
                doSomething(response);
            }, 
            data: {
                format_options : 'callback:' + jQueryAutoGeneratedCallbackFunction,
                outputFormat : 'json'
            }
        }
    );
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..So it turns out I thinking it from a wrong angle. 
The answer is, that I can change the "callback"-parameter like this.

```
   $.ajax("http://mydomain.com/xxx",
    {
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "format_options",
        jsonpCallback:"callback:myFunction",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(response) {
            doSomething(response);
        }, 
        data: {
            foo : "bar"
        }
    }
);
```

Just as clarification, the "callback:"-part in "callback:myFunction" is needed just for the API i'm using, I included it here as i'd included it in the question.